# gridview.count giving range error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWNQf.png)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
var items = [
 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AmmarMohib/Economic-app/master/lib/1.jpeg",
 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AmmarMohib/Economic-app/master/lib/2.jpeg",
 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AmmarMohib/Economic-app/master/lib/3.jpeg",
 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AmmarMohib/Economic-app/master/lib/4.jpeg"
];
var text =[
  "Iphone 12",
  "Iphone 12",
  "Iphone 12",
  "Iphone 12",
];
var reviews =[
  "5.0 (23 reviews)"
  "5.0 (23 reviews)"
  "5.0 (23 reviews)"
  "5.0 (23 reviews)"
];
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Economic app",
     home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
                
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Economic app",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontFamily: 'Lobster',fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,fontSize: 30),),     
        actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.notifications_active,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        print(Text("hello"));
      },
    )
  ],centerTitle: true,backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        body:GridView.count(
                    childAspectRatio: (45/15),

          crossAxisCount: 1,
          mainAxisSpacing: 7.5,
          children: List.generate(items.length , (index) {
         return Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0,right: 20.0,top: 20.0),
           child:ClipRRect(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
             child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(child: Column(
                  children: [
                    GridTile(
                    child: Title(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Row(
                       children: [
                         ClipRRect(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                           child:
                          Image.network(items[index],height: 110,)
                         ),
                         Padding(
                           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:75.0,left: 10),
                           child: Text(text[index],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                         ),
    // IconButton(
    //   icon: Icon(
    //   Icons.star_border_purple500,
    //     color: Colors.yellow,
    //   ),
    //   onPressed: () {
    //   },
    // ),
           Text(reviews[index])
                       ], 
                      )
                    )),
                  ])
                ),
                ),
              ),
           );
          })
          )
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

this is my code, I want to implement the text throw the grid view count, I have done it at top but when I implement at bottom it threws range error that Index out of range Index shouled be less than 1:1,
I have tried a lot but it threw this error,
please help I think that you will understand my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is likely being caused by this `Text(reviews[index])`.
And for your gridview, you are referencing the length based on `items.length`. If the length of `items` does not equal the length of `reviews`, you will get such error.
Try commenting out this text widget.

This is causing your problem:

```
 var reviews = [
    "5.0 (23 reviews)"
        "5.0 (23 reviews)"
        "5.0 (23 reviews)"
        "5.0 (23 reviews)"
  ];
```

The length of this list is `1`. Fix it by adding commas:

```
 var reviews = [
        "5.0 (23 reviews)",
        "5.0 (23 reviews)",
        "5.0 (23 reviews)",
        "5.0 (23 reviews)"
  ];
```

Comment: but I want to show this Text widget and the length is also same